# How to get the model loss in sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Whenever an `sklearn` model is fit to some data, it minimizes some loss function.  How can I obtain the model loss using that loss function?

e.g.

```
model = sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression().fit(X_train,y_train)
model.get_loss(X_train, y_train) #gives the loss for these values
model.get_loss(X_test, y_test) #gives the loss for other values
```

Note that the `.score` method does NOT do this thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`LogisticRegression` minimises log loss, so you would expect the loss to be the `.score`, only negated. However, this actually returns the [mean accuracy](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.score).

To calculate log loss you need to use the [`log_loss`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.log_loss.html) metric:

I haven't tested it, but something like this:

```
from sklearn.metrics import log_loss

model = sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression().fit(X_train, y_train)

loss = log_loss(X_test, model.predict_proba(X_test), eps=1e-15)
```

Comment: it needs to be log_loss(y_test, model.predict(X_test), eps=1e-15)

Comment: `model.predict` gives a thresholded prediction.  I think maybe one needs to use `model.predict_proba`